# Python Regex re.sub not working in For loop

Tags: python, regex, for-loop, text, replace

I am unable to replace a particular occurrence of a certain pattern with edited text. I have used a for...loop to come up with how to get a specific occurrence of the pattern but I am unable to use that with an re.sub statement.

This is my Python 2 code:

```
def split(content):
    count = 0
    s = ""
    for i in re.finditer(r'(?s)(\\thinhline\n\\\\\[-16pt]\n)([a-zA-Z\s\(\)]+)(.*?)(\n *\\\\)', content):
        count= count + 1
        x =  len(re.findall('^\s*&', i.group(3), re.M))
        if x < 6:
            break
        elif x >= 6:
            g = normalizationConstraints(i.group(3),i.group(2)) + "\n"
            s = str(g) + "\n"
            content = re.sub(i,s,content)
    return content
```

The error is on the line:

```
         content = re.sub(i,s,content)
```

Since the variable "i" is apparently not regex.

The error:

```
TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern
```

How can I fix this problem??

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the actual error message?

Comment: what do you think `i` is? have you tried printing `i`?

Comment: That's a lot of backslashes in your regex. Are you sure it's correct? Can you provide an example of what you intend to achieve with this code?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you want, but the error is telling you the right thing: `i` isn't a regex pattern.  [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer) returns an iterator of `MatchObject`s, probably strings in this context.  [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) expects a regular expression pattern as its first argument.

Depending on what you're trying to achieve with this code, you either need to use a different function than `re.sub`, or you need to supply an actual regex.  If you can give more details about your goals (maybe the expected output based on some sample input, as @200_success suggests), that would help.